# TypeError: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I add a item in custom list after the display shortly following errors:

TypeError: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

TypeError: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null referenceSys.ArgumentNullException: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.
[Here is link to tmp workaround](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/167054/14566):

> Edit list view and change field "**Item Text (linked to item with edit menu)**" to 
>   "**Item Text (linked to item)**". Error disappears after that.

Update:

I confirm that install last update (2016-01) solved the problem.

Comment: Worked for me, Thank you!